# Shorter way to write this JavaScript date code

Tags: javascript, date

Hello I want to get today's date in JavaScript in the following format: dd/mm/YYYY

The following code does the job but surely there is a shorter way to write this?

```
    var today = new Date();
    var day = today.getDate();
    var month = today.getMonth()+1;
    var year = today.getFullYear(); 
    var todaysDate = day + "/" + month + "/" + year;
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's a clear way. Just create a function `currentDate` that returns `todaysDate`, and you only need `currentDate()` everywhere you want to use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

recommend a great js date/time lib: http://momentjs.com/

```
moment().format('D/M/YYYY');   //"10/2/2013"
```

if you need padding zeros:

```
moment().format('DD/MM/YYYY'); //"10/02/2013"
```

if you want write pure js, nothing much can do here, just cut off some variable.

```
var today = new Date;
//parenthesis around month is required.
var todaysDate =  today.getDate() + '/' +  (today.getMonth()+1) + '/' + today.getFullYear();
//"10/2/2013"
```

Answer (score 3):

Of course.

```
var date = new Date();
var todaysDate = date.getDate() + "/" + date.getMonth()+1 + "/" + date.getFullYear();
```

Note that this will return values without leading zeros. You can add them using one extra function for convenience:

```
function checkTime(i){if(i<10){i="0" + i}return i}
var date = new Date();
var todaysDate = checkTime(date.getDate()) + "/" + checkTime(date.getMonth()+1) + "/" + date.getFullYear();
```

Comment: You should use `new Date().getMonth()+1`. And this is a tricky way to answer a question. You created the date object 3 times as well.

Comment: @Antony He asked for a shorter version, and I delivered it. My work here is done. Edited to use one `Date()` object

Answer (score 0):

Although JavaScript provides a bunch of methods for getting and setting parts of a date object, it **lacks a simple way to format dates and times according to a user-specified mask**. Yours is quite simple enough.

You could use an external library, but the script size trade-off won't be optimal for just one simple operation.

A shorter version would be to combine the last 4 lines inline this way:

```
var today = new Date();
var todaysDate = today.getDate() + "/" + (today.getMonth()+1) + "/" + today.getFullYear();
```